# How can I insert an array into a specific array element using Jolt

Tags: java, arrays, json, jolt

## Question/problem

How can I use [Jolt](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception) to insert an array into a specific object in an array?

## input

The objects have a common set of attributes, but support optional attributes.

Specific objects need to get these optional attributes depending on their specific position in the array, i.e. second (`[1]`). These optional attributes are to be added as part of the jolt transformation.

```
{
  "array" : [
   {
     "key" : "a key",
     "value" : "a value"
   },
   {
     "key" : "another key",
     "value" : "another value"
   }
  ]
}
```

## expected

```
{
  "array" : [
   {
     "key" : "a key",
     "value" : "a value"
   },
   {
     "key" : "another key",
     "value" : "another value",
     "values": ["extra value1", "extra value2"]
   }
  ]
}
```

## What has been tried

I've tried `default`, `modify-default-beta`, and `modify-overwrite-beta` and none seem to behave the way I thought they did.

### default

Seems like default ignores the array reference `"[1]"` so tried the beta operations which seem to support this.

#### default spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "array": {
        "[1]": {
          "values": ["extra value1", "extra value2"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

#### default actual

```
{
  "array" : [ {
    "key" : "a key",
    "value" : "a value"
  }, {
    "key" : "another key",
    "value" : "another value"
  } ]
}
```

### modify-default-beta

Resolves the array reference `"[1]"`, but only applies the first element in the array from the spec and not the whole array

#### modify-default-beta spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "array": {
        "[1]": {
          "values": ["extra value1", "extra value2"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

#### modify-default-beta actual

```
{
  "array" : [ {
    "key" : "a key",
    "value" : "a value"
  }, {
    "key" : "another key",
    "value" : "another value",
    "values" : "extra value1" // array is dumped
  } ]
}
```

### modify-overwrite-beta

Tried `modify-overwrite-beta` and I get the same behaviour as `modify-default-beta`.

#### modify-overwrite-beta spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "array": {
        "[1]": {
          "values": ["extra value1", "extra value2"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

#### modify-overwrite-beta actual

```
{
  "array" : [ {
    "key" : "a key",
    "value" : "a value"
  }, {
    "key" : "another key",
    "value" : "another value",
    "values" : "extra value1" // array is dumped
  } ]
}
```

## Interesting side note

Without the array reference on the input this is a fairly easy problem, it seems the behaviour is not what I am expecting when there is an array reference and the `*-beta` operations.

### simple default

I've gotten rid of the array from the input

#### simple default input

```
{
  "element1": {
    "key": "a key",
    "value": "a value"
  },
  "element2": {
    "key": "a key",
    "value": "another value"
  }
}
```

#### simple default spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "element2": {
        "values": ["extra value1", "extra value2"]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

#### simple default actual

```
{
  "element1" : {
    "key" : "a key",
    "value" : "a value"
  },
  "element2" : {
    "key" : "another key",
    "value" : "another value",
    "values" : [ "extra value1", "extra value2" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be my misunderstanding of the usage of the spec.

It appears that you don't insert an array, but each element that you want to insert.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "array": {
        "[1]": {
          "values": {
            "[0]": "extra value1",
            "[1]": "extra value2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The spec above is inserting both values into the values attribute and specifically into element `"[0]"` and element `"[1]"`.

This also works with the `modify-overwrite-beta` operation

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "array": {
        "[1]": {
          "values": {
            "[0]": "extra value1",
            "[1]": "extra value2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the result of both of these specs is as follows:

```
{
  "array" : [ {
    "key" : "a key",
    "value" : "a value"
  }, {
    "key" : "another key",
    "value" : "another value",
    "values" : [ "extra value1", "extra value2" ]
  } ]
}
```